# Scrolling animation JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, scroll, datepicker

I'm using JQuery UI to add a calendar in my [web page](http://www.adrianensemble.it/dev/calendar.html) and I used

```
window.location.href
```

to go to a anchor clicking on a date in the calendar with the

```
onSelect
```

event of JQuery UI date picker. 
Anyone can suggest **how to smooth scrolling** with JQuery in the onSelect event?
The js code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(function() {
var events = [ 
{ Title: "#DETAILS", Date: new Date("09/13/2011") }, 
{ Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("09/25/2011") }, 
{ Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("10/01/2011") }
];

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var result = [true, '', null];
    var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
        return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
    });

    if (matching.length) {
        result = [true, 'highlight', null];
    }
    return result;
},
onSelect: function(date) {
       window.location.href = "#"+date;
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe using a jQuery plugin like [this one](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll)?

Comment: @Franquis You should move your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using a jQuery plugin like [this one](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll)?

```
[...]
onSelect: function(date) {
       $.smoothScroll({
        scrollTarget: "#"+date
        });
    }
```

Comment: Ok I'm trying to use this but it seems not to get the "date" and it scroll to "#", i.e. to the top. Do you know how to adjust this?

Comment: Well actually it's now only scrolling at top, and not to the "scrollTarget"

Comment: Have you tried this?

`$onSelect: function(date) {
var date1 = "#"+date;
       $.smoothScroll({
        scrollTarget: date1
        });
    }
`